# how to get similar products tags in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have products table , each product have tags stored in this way

"tag1,tag2,tag3" (string)

now when I display a product - I want to display all products have any tag related to the current one

for example

```
product1 -> tags (tag1,tag2,tag3)
product2 -> tags (tag3,tag4,tag5)
product3 -> tags (tag4,tag5,tag6)
```

for example in product 1 -> it should catch product 2 because it have same tag (tag3)

unfortunately I didn't write any code - I am not sure how to implement it

Comment: products and tags are two tables ?

Comment: Question is not clear. Give us more information.

Comment: If products and tags are two tables then you simply join products to tags table and select where tag name is equal to your current tag.

Comment: No - I don't have table for tags

Comment: start by normalizing your database..using comma separated values within SQL is clumsy... And besides if you use comma separated values extraction queries becomes much more complex..

Comment: So this is the way to implement it.

Comment: so - I have to create a separated table for tags -> Okey thanks

Comment: "I have to create a separated table for tags " -> No you need to have the tables  `product`  `product_tags` and `tags` because the relation between product and a tag is many to many.. A product can contain many tags.. And a tag can belong to many products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this with hard way. If you make your database good it will be helpful to achieve any type of search. You can create two tables

```
1) Products (column :- id, name) 2) product_tags(column :- id, product_id, tag_name)
```

With this structure you can fetch any type of products.

If you don't want to go with above part and try this as per your requirement. Now i am assuming you have three records in products table that are as follow:-

```
ID product_name  product_tags
1   product1       tag1,tag2,tag3
2   product2       tag3,tag4,tag5
3   product3       tag4,tag5,tag6
```

Now as per your requirement you are showing `Product1` in webpage and may be you are showing similar tag products.
So your logic will be like this:-

```
$productDetail = Product:where('product_name','product1')->first();  // this query will return tags of `product1`
 $productDetail = json_decode(json_encode($productDetail),true); //convert to array
if(!empty($productDetail)){
   $producttags = explode(',',$productDetail['product_tags']);
   $productids = array();
   foreach($producttags as $tag){
       $getproducts = Product::whereRaw("find_in_set($tag,product_tags)")->get();
      $getproducts= json_decode(json_encode($getproducts),true);
      if(!empty($getproducts)){
          foreach($getproducts as $product){
               $productids[] = $product['id'];
           }
       }
    }
   $productids = array_unique($productids);
  }
  echo "<pre>"; print_r($productids); // print the productids here and after that use `whereIn` for fetcch tag product ids
```

Hope it helps! Good Luck for your Project